# $f \in C[a,b]$ be such that $\int_c^d f(x)dx=0 , \forall c,d \in [a,b] , c<d$ ; then $f$ is identically zero on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int_c^d f(x)dx=0 , \forall c,d \in [a,b] , c<d$ ; then is it true that $f(x)=0 , \forall x \in [a,b]$ ?

Comment: What is the integral equal to?

Comment: i think, it is equal zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you mean $\int_c^d f(x)dx= 0 , \forall c,d \in [a,b] , c<d$

Then it is true that $f(x)=0 ,\forall x \in [a,b]$, to see that look at 
 $ x \to \int_a^x f(t)dt $, this function is equal to $ x \to 0 $ so by differentiating you can see that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in ]a,b[ $ and by continuity we have $f(x)=0, \forall x \in [a,b] $

Answer (score 1):

Another way can be this. Assume not, then since the function is continuous exists $\left[c,d\right]\in\left[a,b\right],\, c<d
 $ such that $f\left(x\right)\neq0,\ \forall x\in\left[c,d\right]
 $. For hypothesis we have $$\int_{c}^{d}f\left(x\right)=0
 $$ but since $f
 $ is continuous we have, using the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration), that exists some $t\in\left[c,d\right]
 $ such that $$\int_{c}^{d}f\left(x\right)=f\left(t\right)\left(c-d\right)
 $$ and this is absurd because $f\left(t\right)\neq0
 $.